# How do I get solcjs to compile yul

Tags: evm, solc, assembly, solcjs

I want to write a smart contract using pure Yul but I have no idea how I'm meant to configure / run `solcjs` to compile my yul code down to bytecode. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You compile yul with the command

```
solc --strict-assembly path
```

solcjs doesn't have this option, so you can just install solc. The installer is on their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.8.13)